# Access PC with domain in LAN

Tags: windows, ubuntu, domain-name-system, ip, local-area-network

I recently installed in our (small) company GitLab and the built-in Mattermost in a dsktop-PC runnin Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS, which will work as server for Gitlab, Mattermost and maybe intern Wordpress or a wiki.

At the moment I can access

- Gitlab = http://192.168.150.33
- Mattermost = http://192.168.150.33:5050

Now, it would be great if my colleagues could reach the systems through for example gitlab.company.com and mattermost.company.com.

All my coleagues PCs are running Win7, so AFAIK I could edit in each PC (~15) the hosts file.

- Is this the best way to do it?
- Could I make an entry pointing directly to 192.168.150:5050 (with port-number)?

Thanks in advance :smiley

Comment: That's what DNS servers are for.

Comment: This question doesn't really belong on this exchange, as you're in so many words asking "How do I set up DNS?". This is more of a Q+A for solving individual problems with existing implementations in production or pre-prod environments. If you have a specific question you would like to ask beyond requesting training, you might restructure the question to reflect that.

Comment: Where's your https nginx proxy... Both of those systems should be behind encryption

Answer (score 1):

If you have a public domain available, you can add **A** records for those two hostnames within that domain. Yes the records can point to any valid IP address, not neccesarily public one.

You can also set up a DNS proxy on a linux machine within that private network and with **DHCP**'s help point everyone to that DNS server, which would serve additional records not publicly available. ( for example you can do this with `dnsmasq` or `pdnsd` and of course the DNS workhorse - `bind` )